# Change Language of the Windows Phone Emulator using Coded UI

Tags: c#, windows-phone, coded-ui-tests

I have to do the localization testing of the Windows Phone application. For doing localization testing of this application I have to change the language of the emulator through the settings option and restart the emulator.

Can someone please help me to achieve this scenario using Coded UI?

Is there any other way to change the language of the application without changing the phone language?